# Generate multiple buttons for distinct list elements

Tags: button

I have a lot of data sets. I want to plot all of them and export some of them to file (or print them as in example below) by clicking buttons generated next to plots.

```
(*Create list of 5 random data sets*)
datalist = RandomInteger[10, {5, 20}];

(*Plot all data sets and create buttons to print raw data*)
Table[{ListPlot[data], Button["Print data", Print[data]]}, {data, datalist}]//Grid
```

My approach is not working, as the action of the button is executed outside of the scope of 'Table' function. How can I procedurally generate distinct buttons binded to different elements from list?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's a typical use of `With[]`:

```
(*Create list of 5 random data sets*)
datalist = RandomInteger[10, {5, 20}];

(*Plot all data sets and create buttons to print raw data*)
Table[
  {ListPlot[data],
   With[{data00=data},Button["Print data",Print[data00]]]},
  {data, datalist}] // 
Grid
```

`data00=data ... Print[data00]` could perfectly be replaced by `data=data ... Print[data]`

[image]

When you push a button, then the data are printed :

> {5,4,3,9,10,9,2,9,4,5,9,6,8,5,0,9,4,9,6,4}

Answer (score 1):

```
Grid[{ListPlot[#], Button["Print", Print[#]]} & /@ datalist]
```