# How to create multiple plots by looping through variables

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

Consider the following MWE:

```
Ps = {P1, P2, P3}
f[betas_] := betas.betas

(*A) works as expected:*)
Plot[f[{P1, P2, P3}] /. {P1 -> 5, P2 -> 10, P3 -> 15}, {P1, 0, 10}]
Plot[f[{P1, P2, P3}] /. {P1 -> 5, P2 -> 10, P3 -> 15}, {P2, 0, 10}]
Plot[f[{P1, P2, P3}] /. {P1 -> 5, P2 -> 10, P3 -> 15}, {P3, 0, 10}]

(*B) does not work:*)
Table[Show[
  Plot[f[Ps] /. {P1 -> 5, P2 -> 10, P3 -> 15}, {Ps[[k]], 0, 10}]], {k,
   Length[Ps]}]
```

I try to get the three graphs in A) by looping through Ps in B), but can't get it running.

Comment: Essentially a [duplicate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/169480/19530).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error indicates that `Ps[[k]]` cannot be used as an iterator. A workaround:

```
Table[With[{p = Ps[[k]]}, 
  Plot[f[Ps] /. {P1 -> 5, P2 -> 10, P3 -> 15}, {p, 0, 10}]], {k, Length[Ps]}]
```

Comment: Uh, did you redefine `Pi`? While this is perfectly valid, I have my doubts wether we should teach that as good programming practice ;)

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Oh, I hadn't even realized! Thanks for pointing that out :) That's why I don't usually don't use upper-case names..